Pulse Secure Client is not able to load SAM transport device in Docker Windows Container
I'm trying to create a Windows Container as a VPN Gateway:

It runs the Pulse Client to connect to a VPN;
I connect to the container through RDP + SSH tunnel;
Allowing me to reach the VPN

Reason:
I would use Pulse Client on my laptop but, due to restrictions made by my company, it doesn't work.
At the moment I'm using it in a VM but I want to get rid of it.
Issue:
I reviewed the client logs and after a lot of headache it seems to me that the cause resides to the impossibility for it to load the PulseSAM device:
00164,09 2024/08/29 16:26:13.171 4 SYSTEM PulseSecureService.exe samAM p2704 t478 WfpManager.cpp:594 - 'WfpManager' openWFPDevice:: CreateFile ErrorCode=1834088004 retry=0
00194,09 2024/08/29 16:26:13.171 3 SYSTEM PulseSecureService.exe samAM p2704 t478 WfpManager.cpp:599 - 'WfpManager' openWFPDevice:: CreateFile failed for Pulse transport device:\\.\PulseSAM ErrorCode=0
00172,09 2024/08/29 16:26:13.171 3 SYSTEM PulseSecureService.exe samAM p2704 t478 WfpManager.cpp:696 - 'WfpManager' openWFPDevice::Pulse transport device:\\.\PulseSAM Error Code=0
00147,09 2024/08/29 16:26:13.171 3 SYSTEM PulseSecureService.exe samAM p2704 t478 WfpManager.cpp:352 - 'WSAMWFPProxy' openWFPDevice failed with Error=1105
00152,09 2024/08/29 16:26:13.171 3 SYSTEM PulseSecureService.exe samAM p2704 t478 WfpManager.cpp:375 - 'CWfpManager' CWfpManager::stop Tunnel has not started

00151,09 2024/08/29 16:26:13.171 3 SYSTEM PulseSecureService.exe samAM p2704 t478 WfpManager.cpp:67 - 'CWfpManager' CWfpManager::Release .DeleteInstance n=1..
00148,09 2024/08/29 16:26:13.171 3 SYSTEM PulseSecureService.exe samAM p2704 t478 WfpManager.cpp:707 - 'WfpManager' ++WfpDeviceEnableRedirection (DISABLE)

00165,09 2024/08/29 16:26:13.171 1 SYSTEM PulseSecureService.exe samAM p2704 t478 WfpManager.cpp:753 - 'WfpManager' WfpDeviceEnableRedirection::DeviceIoControl Error Code=6
00158,09 2024/08/29 16:26:13.171 3 SYSTEM PulseSecureService.exe samAM p2704 t478 WfpManager.cpp:759 - 'WfpManager' WfpDeviceEnableRedirection (DISABLE)->0x00000006

00152,09 2024/08/29 16:26:13.171 3 SYSTEM PulseSecureService.exe samAM p2704 t478 WfpManager.cpp:375 - 'CWfpManager' CWfpManager::stop Tunnel has not started

00162,09 2024/08/29 16:26:13.172 4 SYSTEM PulseSecureService.exe samAM p2704 t478 WfpManager.cpp:423 - 'WfpManager' Attempting to stop 'PulseSAM' driver if it is running
00146,09 2024/08/29 16:26:13.172 3 SYSTEM PulseSecureService.exe samAM p2704 t478 WfpManager.cpp:483 - 'WfpManager' 'PulseSAM' Driver Service Not running
00196,09 2024/08/29 16:26:13.172 1 SYSTEM PulseSecureService.exe samAM p2704 t478 samAccessMethod.cpp:499 - 'samAccessMethod' onPcpClientConfig m_pcpListener->onPcpClientConfig failed with errorcode:1105
00181,09 2024/08/29 16:26:13.172 4 SYSTEM PulseSecureService.exe samAM p2704 t478 samAccessMethod.cpp:267 - 'samAccessMethod' sendConnectionStatus state:5, stage:1, iErr:1105, iErrorNum:0.
00183,09 2024/08/29 16:26:13.172 4 SYSTEM PulseSecureService.exe iveConnectionMethod p2704 t478 connInstance.cpp:1812 - 'iveConnectionMethod' Received channel status samAccessMethod 5 1 1105
00143,09 2024/08/29 16:26:13.172 4 SYSTEM PulseSecureService.exe dsAccessService p2704 t478 dsaccessworkqueue.cpp:276 - 'WorkQueue' Queued work unit 4
00285,09 2024/08/29 16:26:13.172 4 SYSTEM PulseSecureService.exe dsAccessService p2704 t818 dsaccessworkqueue.cpp:382 - 'WorkQueue' Start running work unit 4 (taskQueue_1ff1535e4099a143b18493751f9bb13e - class DSAccessObject<class iveCon
nectionInstance::amErrorHandler>-connInstance.cpp:1817)

I'm assuming this because I see that right afterwards it starts a retry and also because I compared the Container logs with my VM pulse logs and I don't have this error in the latter one.
Some specs:

Host: Windows 10 Enterprise 22H2 19045.4780
Container: Windows 20H2
Pulse Secure Client: 22.6.1.26825

This is my simple Dockerfile:
# escape=`
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:20H2

ARG REG_PATH=HKLM:/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/AppModelUnlock
COPY ./ps-pulse-win-22.6r1.0-b26825-64bit-installer.msi .
COPY ./OpenSSH-Win64 ./OpenSSH-Win64
COPY ./sshd_config .
COPY ./entrypoint.ps1 .

RUN Powershell -Command `
    Write-Host 'Setting PS execution policy'; `
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force; `
    `
    Write-Host 'Creating Admin user'; `
    NET USER Admin "Password01!" /ADD; `
    NET LOCALGROUP "Administrators" "Admin" /ADD; `
    `
    Write-Host 'Enabling Developer mode'; `
    if (-not(Test-Path -Path $ENV:REG_PATH)) { `
        New-Item -Path $ENV:REG_PATH -ItemType Directory -Force; `
    } `
    New-ItemProperty -Path $ENV:REG_PATH -Name AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense -PropertyType DWORD -Value 1; `
    `
    Write-Host 'Enabling Windows Defender'; `
    Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\WinDefend\\' -Name 'Start' -Value 3; `
    Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\WinDefend\\' -Name 'LaunchProtected' -Value 0; `
    `
    Write-Host 'Installing Pulse Secure...'; `
    Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/passive /qn /i "C:\\ps-pulse-win-22.6r1.0-b26825-64bit-installer.msi" /L* "msilogs.log"'; `
    `
    Write-Host 'Installing sshd service...'; `
    Powershell -File './OpenSSH-Win64/install-sshd.ps1'; `
    `
    if(Test-Path 'C:\\ProgramData\\ssh\\sshd_config') { `
        Move-Item 'C:\\ProgramData\\ssh\\sshd_config' 'C:\\ProgramData\\ssh\\sshd_config_default' -Force; `
    } `
    Copy-Item './sshd_config' 'C:\\ProgramData\\ssh\\sshd_config' -Force; `
    `
    Write-Host 'Setting sshd service startup...'; `
    Set-Service sshd -StartupType Automatic

That I run as follows:
docker run --name pulse-secure-vpn -i -d --network="Default Switch" --dns 8.8.8.8 pulse-secure

I know that this is specific to Pulse, but my assumption is that the Container is missing any relevant Service running or any Network configuration.
I tried many configurations (Nano Server, Core Server and now Windows 20H2) but I'm not able to figure out why it doesn't connect to the VPN.
The other versions were missing other components needed by VPN policies (e.g. any antivirus. In Windows 20H2 I'm able to run Windows Defender that's enough)
I tried also an older version of Pulse Secure Client with the same result.
